# How to do multiple select sum sub-queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, aggregate-functions, multiple-tables

This is my first post so if I do anything incorrectly concerning the post please correct me.

I am creating a scoring program for a fishing competition.
I have the following tables(I am only going to list the columns of interest:

## tblScores:

|Column Name|

- Pk_CatchID
- Fk_AnglerID
- Day
- Fk_FishID
- Points

## tblAnglers:

|Column Name|

- Pk_AnglerID
- Fk_BoatID
- Name

## tblBoats:

|Column Name|

- Pk_BoatID
- BoatName

Now what I want to do is create a score sheet for a whole week of competition, which is 5 days. So I have to do a sum of the scores and use the respective foreign keys to sum the scores for each boat.

This is what I have currently:

```
Select BoatName, " +
             "Sum(tblScores.Points) AS [Day 1] " +
             "from tblScores INNER JOIN tblAnglers ON tblScores.Fk_AnglerID=tblAnglers.Pk_AnglerID " +
            " INNER JOIN tblBoats ON tblAnglers.Fk_BoatID=tblBoats.Pk_BoatID "
            + " where Day=1 GROUP BY BoatName
```

This works perfectly fine for one day, but what I would like to do is view this data in a DataGridView with columns for each day and then a total column as well.

Something like this:

```
|Boat Name|Day 1|Day 2|Day 3|Day 4|Day 5|Total|
|Example1 | 50  | 30  | 65  | 35  | 40  | 220 |
|Example2 | 40  | 50  | 70  | 35  | 30  | 225 |
```

I have tried using nested selects but I could not get this to work. I am open to suggestions on how this can be solved.

Also my other thought was to create a new table and keep these scores for each day in there(or even in the boats table) but I feel that the structure of the database would not be as good as data would be repeated. But I could be wrong.

Thank you all!

Also: I am using Visual Studio 2013 (C#) and Microsoft SQL Server 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
    BoatName,  
    Sum(Case When Day = 1 Then tblScores.Points Else 0 End) AS [Day1],
    Sum(Case When Day = 2 Then tblScores.Points Else 0 End) AS [Day2],
    Sum(Case When Day = 3 Then tblScores.Points Else 0 End) AS [Day3],
    Sum(Case When Day = 4 Then tblScores.Points Else 0 End) AS [Day4],
    Sum(Case When Day = 5 Then tblScores.Points Else 0 End) AS [Day5],
    Sum(tblScores.Points) As Total
From tblScores 
INNER JOIN tblAnglers ON tblScores.Fk_AnglerID=tblAnglers.Pk_AnglerID
INNER JOIN tblBoats ON tblAnglers.Fk_BoatID=tblBoats.Pk_BoatID
GROUP BY BoatName
Order By BoatName
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/986c1/2)

Comment: Hello thank you for your suggestion! It is very close to what I want to achieve and have gotten the same before, however the problem is that this splits the results by Boat and Day. Which produces something like the following: BoatName Day1 Day2: Boat1 Score1 0 and then Boat1 0 Score2 in a new row.

Comment: Just had a thought, if there is no way to do exactly what I want I could loop through these results and fix them up in C#. But I would like to solve this using SQL alone if possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  This shows the data exactly like the table in your question.  Check out the fiddle.

Comment: Yes sorry your edited answer works perfectly. I appreciate your help. I also see now what my problem was. Thank you!